# QTextBrowser don't show contents when loading markdown file

Tags: python, pyqt5, markdown

The characteristic of markdown are showed perfectly in QTextBrowser, except for the contents showed as original [TOC] which not be rendered.

Here is the code:

```
class textDemo(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initGUI()

    def initGUI(self):
        fileName = QUrl('tutorial.md')
        filePath = os.path.dirname(__file__)
        browser = QTextBrowser()
        browser.setSearchPaths([filePath])
        browser.setSource(fileName)

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(browser)
        self.setLayout(layout)

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
w = textDemo()
w.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The markdown file tutorial.md is below:

```
[TOC]

# The tutorial for snpExplore software


## Home

This is a comprehensive module in snpExplore software, which can conduct most of build-in analyses.


## Frequency
```

The PyQt5 5.14 version was used in this example. The snapshot is :

[image]

Comment: share the tutorial.md

Comment: The tutorial.md is showed above.